# How to configure ElasticPress WordPress plugin to leverage exsting Elasticsearch index for autocomplete searchbox

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Facts:

- Using existing Wordpress 4.8 implementation Added Elasticpress plugin
- Have existing Elasticsearch 5.4 environment
- Loaded 1,000 JSON documents from file, and successfully created an
  index
- Relevant fields in index: carName, carURI

Looking to create simple webpage in order to implement an autocomplete scenario, whereby user would begin searching for item by name (a car, let's say), searching against (carName) in the index, and gets a limited number of matching results for carName, with URI link to relevant webpage (carURI).

Upon reading documentation for ElasticPress, it appears primarily to index a Wordpress site, and commit it to ES as an index, and use it to search captured site data.  Can it be leveraged as a search target from an *existing* index in ES?